# Convert with variable change the form Sturm- Liouville to $y^{\prime\prime}+(\lambda \rho_{1}(x)+q_{1}(x))y=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I have the problem of Sturm Liouville in $[a,b]:$
$$
\left(p(x) y^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+(\lambda \rho(x)-q(x))y=0,
$$
developing the expression I got:
$$
p(x)y^{\prime\prime}+p(x)^{\prime}.y^{\prime}+(\lambda \rho(x)-q(x))y=0
$$
by changing the variable I must arrive at the expression:
$$
y^{\prime\prime}+(\lambda \rho_{1}(x)+q_{1}(x))y=0 
$$

the problem is not about reducing but making a change of variable,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a $\rho(x)$ in your first equation?

Comment: My first equation is $\left(p(x) y^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+(\lambda \rho(x)-q(x)) y=0$

Comment: You go from \begin{align}
(\lambda\rho(x)-q(x))y\end{align}
to \begin{align}
(\lambda p(x)-q(x))y\end{align} from eqn 1 to 2

Comment: Am I crazy? You have \begin{align}
(\lambda\color{red}{\rho(x)}-q(x))y\end{align}
to \begin{align}
(\lambda \color{red}{p(x)}-q(x))y\end{align}

Comment: The original question is to convert $(p(x) u^{\prime})^{\prime}+(\lambda \rho(x)-q(x)) u=0$ --> $u^{\prime\prime}+( \lambda \rho_{1}(x)-q_{1}(x))u$ with variable change

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=h(x)u$, do your product rules and collect all your terms to get an ODE of the form
\begin{align}
f_1(x)u''+f_2(x)u'+f_3(x)u=0.
\end{align}
Set $f_2(x)$ to zero. This will give you an easy ODE to solve for $h(x)$ in terms of $p(x)$ which will simplify it to the form you desire.